# Setting user id or user name in Session is safe?

Tags: php, session

I'm i Newbie and i have a question, I want to build a php script that the security is 50%.
I just want to make a login system based on php sessions.

So as i read in learnings on internet, we can store user id OR user name in session like :

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;
```

So, is it safe to do this ?

Can anyone else build a fake session and access to admin area ?

If it is possible, What is the solution ? Can we store Hashed Password in session ?!

Comment: You can store hashed password in session, but it would be of no use. The highest threat to session usage like this would be someone who steals cookie from an admin. However there are means to protect against that: For example you can store user's IP at the time they log in and check it every time you register a session. There is very low chance that someone who steals your session will have same IP as you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session values are stored on the server. Therefore it is not possible to get or change the contents of a session from the client side.

The only way someone could create a session is either through your script or if they have access to your server (in which case you have bigger problems).

It is however possible for someone to get access to someone else's session using a cookie stealer but that is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

it is safe if you are building a session after `login authentication` of username. and session are resides on server. so cannot be rebuild session without login authentication

so anybody has to be login with authorise usename and password to build the session.

Where as a more secure way is to generate a `long random string` mixed with `letters and digits` as `login key` and store it in the database to the authenticated user

Now store `login key` into the `sessio`n and access username and password with that particular user's username by `login key` stored in the session

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to fake a session, but it's not so easy as stealing a cookie, so it's kinda safe, if you don't have a website, where people do something with money, then it should be better to introduce some encryption.